# jpg wont display on page unless I am using live server

Tags: css, background-image

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 72, 121, 0.7),rgba(64, 86, 97, 0.7)),url(/images/background.jpg);
```

This image shows up when I use live server, but when using a regular server only the gradient is displayed. Really confused as to why this is happening, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that the image is in the correct folder on the server? Try putting in the full URL and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server isn't serving /images/background.jpg. Try navigating to there in your browser and see what HTTP response code it returns. I'd cast my bet that the images directory simply isn't being included by the server or is inaccessible due to misconfigured file permissions.